# Undefined method 'dateTime' for Google::ApiClient

Tags: ruby, datetime, google-api-ruby-client

Im working on a sinatra based application, in which I get events from a google calendar and display all events as a list. However I have encountered an unusual error when I tried to get the start and end dates of All day events.

Since all day events have an object of type Date, and timed events have an object of type dateTime , these two objects won't get displayed, the error I get is:

*no such method named dateTime*

It works fine when there is only timed events (dateTime object) events but not when there is an all day event (date object).

Any help would be great.

Code:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'google/api_client'
require 'date'
 # modified from 1m

  # Update these to match your own apps credentials
  service_account_email = "" # Email of service account
  key_file = "" # File containing your private key
  key_secret = 'notasecret' # Password to unlock private key

  # Get the Google API client
  client = Google::APIClient.new(:application_name => 'GCalendar', 
    :application_version => '1.0.0')

  # Load your credentials for the service account
  key = Google::APIClient::KeyUtils.load_from_pkcs12(key_file, key_secret)
  client.authorization = Signet::OAuth2::Client.new(
    :token_credential_uri => 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token',
    :audience => 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token',
    :scope => 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar',
    :issuer => service_account_email,
    :signing_key => key)

  motd = Array.new

  summary = ""
  description = ""
  tickerEvent = " "
  # Start the scheduler

  # Request a token for our service account
  client.authorization.fetch_access_token!

  # Get the calendar API
  calendar = client.discovered_api('calendar','v3')
  today = DateTime.now().to_s
  # Execute the query
  result = client.execute(:api_method => calendar.events.list,
  :parameters => {'calendarId' => 'idNo', 
    'timeMin' => today,
    'singleEvents' => true,
    'orderBy' => 'startTime'})

  events = result.data.items
  events.each do |e|
    if(DateTime.now() >= e.start.dateTime)
        summary = e.summary
      description = e.description
      tickerEvent = summary.to_s + " - "  +description.to_s
      motd.push(tickerEvent)
    elsif(DateTime.now() >= e.end.dateTime)
      motd.delete(e)
    end
  end
  motd.clear
end
```

Is there a way to check whether the event is a Date type or a DateTime type?

In the google api the start dateTime and end dateTime looks like (This is a timed event):

```
"start": {
    "dateTime": "2013-12-03T12:30:00+13:00",
    "timeZone": "Pacific/Auckland"
   },
   "end": {
    "dateTime": "2013-12-03T13:00:00+13:00",
    "timeZone": "Pacific/Auckland"
   },
```

whereas an all day event looks like:

```
"start": {
    "date": "2014-01-17"
   },
   "end": {
    "date": "2014-01-18"
   },
```

they are of different types, this is what is causing the error.

Cheers

Comment: the dateTime method is from the google api client not from ruby

Comment: please include the code...

Comment: You are comparing an apple to an orange. Can you show what a `dateTime` looks like when a timed even vs. an all day event? You should create a Rails DateTime object from the `dateTime` you are getting from Google, then compare them.

Comment: did you find a solution. I'm fiddling with the same problems here.

Comment: No still haven't found a solution yet.

Comment: Any one found a solution yet?

Answer (score 0):

The method is `event.start.date_time` not `event.start.dateTime`.

For events that do not have a time associated with them, `event.start.date_time` will return nil.  You can then call `event.start.date`, which should return just the date.